# Using auto-fill value in repeat() function doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to learn css-grid layout. I've turned on the grid flags for Chrome, FireFox and FireFox Developer. I've also downloaded FireFox nightly (as of today 52.0a1 (2016-11-07) (64-bit)). I'm on a Mac.

My plan was that I wanted to use the `auto-fill` feature to ensure an even number of columns. So I did this:

```
.wrapper {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 2.5vw 2.5vw);
}
```

In Chrome that worked, but in all the FF I see an `invalid property value` error in the debugger.

I'm looking at [this grid example](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2015/06/19/css-grid-layout-solving-the-gutter-problem/) from Rachel Andrew and in the third example she shows using a fixed number of a repeating pattern:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, [col] 4fr [gutter] 3.5fr ) [col] 4fr [gutter];
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(4, [row] auto [gutter] 15px);
}
```

I've tried changing the repeat count to number and it works in all my browsers. But `auto-fill` seems to only work in Chrome. I know the standard hasn't been released yet, but is this how it is supposed to be?

Is there some other technique for ensuring an even number of columns that will fit into a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `auto-fill` value works in both Chrome and Firefox.

The problem seems to be in your code:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 2.5vw 2.5vw);
```

This code does not conform with the required syntax for the `repeat()` function with `auto-fill`:

> [**7.2.2.1. Syntax of `repeat()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax)
>
> The precise syntax of the `repeat()` notation has several forms:
>
> ```
> <track-repeat> = repeat( [ <positive-integer> ] , [ <line-names>? <track-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
>
> <auto-repeat>  = repeat( [ auto-fill | auto-fit ] , [ <line-names>? <fixed-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
>
> <fixed-repeat> = repeat( [ <positive-integer> ] , [ <line-names>? <fixed-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
> ```

Based on the syntax definition for `<auto-repeat>`, you can only have *one fixed size* value in the argument. You have two.

So the problem wasn't the first argument (`auto-fill`). It was the second.

Once you remove the duplicate `2.5vw`, Firefox accepts the rule as valid. (Chrome apparently was ignoring the duplicate from the beginning.)

```css
grid-container {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 2.5vw 2.5vw); */ /* INVALID */
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 2.5vw); */       /* VALID */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25ch, 1fr)); /* VALID */
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

grid-item {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<grid-container>
  <grid-item>1</grid-item>
  <grid-item>2</grid-item>
  <grid-item>3</grid-item>
  <grid-item>4</grid-item>
  <grid-item>5</grid-item>
  <grid-item>6</grid-item>
  <grid-item>7</grid-item>
</grid-container>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuby7n54/3/)

Comment: This looks great. It's been a bit since I was looking into this. My original goal was to ensure an even number of columns. Do you see a way to do that?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't think `auto-fill` or `auto-fit` are the right solution for that. You may need to define the number of grid columns per row, and then use media queries to force an even number among screen sizes.

Comment: At the same time, I'm on my first reading of the Grid Layout spec, so there may be a more efficient solution that I haven't discovered yet.